# Hibernate exception while using GWT

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt

I'm using a very simple GWT class, that sends a String to the server, then the server sends this to a hibernate session and adds the field to a database, relatively simple stuff.

My code is as follows...

```
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
    GreetingService {

public String greetServer(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    // Verify that the input is valid. 
    if (!FieldVerifier.isValidName(input)) {
        // If the input is not valid, throw an IllegalArgumentException back to
        // the client.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Name must be at least 4 characters long");
    }

    // Escape data from the client to avoid cross-site script vulnerabilities.
    input = escapeHtml(input);
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName(input);
    DaoFactory factory = new DaoFactory();
    try {
        factory.create(user);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "User : " + input + " added";
}

/**
 * Escape an html string. Escaping data received from the client helps to
 * prevent cross-site script vulnerabilities.
 * 
 * @param html the html string to escape
 * @return the escaped string
 */
private String escapeHtml(String html) {
    if (html == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return html.replaceAll("&", "&amp;").replaceAll("<", "&lt;")
            .replaceAll(">", "&gt;");
}
```

This is where it looks like it exceptions, when I run my app, all works fine until I click the button that invokes this method and I get the following exception...

```
    [ERROR] javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.behaviour.app.client.GreetingService.greetServer(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session
    at com.behaviour.app.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 41 more
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?  My hibernate class is shown below...

```
package com.behaviour.beans;

import javax.persistence.Column;

@Entity
public class User {

    private int userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;


    @Id
    @Column(name = "userid", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = true)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = true)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the code, but that the Hibernate jar is missing. In particular, the application cannot find the class `org.hibernate.Session`.

Comment: hmm, this doesn't appear to be the case as if I run a test class with just User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName(input);
    DaoFactory factory = new DaoFactory(); and then commit the user, it works fine, so it's not missing the jar

Comment: You probably don't get the error on your unit tests because the classpath is different. The error is **very**, **very** clear, java cannot find the Session class.

Comment: It's not on a unit test class, it's an actual class in the same package that uses the same classpath.

Comment: Ah, it was because the libs were in the classpath and build path, but not in the WEB-INF for GWT, thank you.